# problem with bit in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
resultset = statemet.executequery("select shift+0 from sportman");

string x = resultset.getstring("shift");
```

but second line throw exception:

```
Column 'shift' not found.
```

shift is `bit(8)` and i want to show it to form `'000101'`.

Comment: have you tried `resultset.getstring("shift+0");` ?

Comment: yes but it returned for example **45** but i want it was in the form of **01010**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.valueOf(resultset.getString("shift+0")))
```

Result is not zero-padded to the width you want though. You may need to add that yourself later.